# How to proper use clipboard.js within Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, clipboard.js

I'm making my pet-project using [Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/). One of the small features I'd like to implement is copying some dynamic data to clipboard. For such tasks I have always used `clipboard.js`, but never within `Nuxt.js`.

Tthe solution I wrote is working, but I'm not sure that I used it proper way.

```html
<button class="copyToClipboardBtn" data-clipboard-target="#output">Copy</button>
...
<textarea id="output">some dynamically generated text</textarea>
```

```js
import ClipboardJS from "clipboard";

export default { // component
  data() {
    return {
      clipboard: null, // data-property for storing clipboard instance
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.copyToClipboardBtn');
  },
  destroyed() {
    if ( this.clipboard ) {
      this.clipboard.destroy();
    }
  },
}
```

So, my question is **how to properly use such a libraries within Nuxt**?

I'm using `Nuxt.js 2.14.7` and `clipboard.js 2.0.6` (https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, for simplicity you would want to use a vue wrapper of this plugin and then import it as a nuxt plugin.

For example with this wrapper:
https://github.com/Inndy/vue-clipboard2

`plugins/vueClipboard2.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueClipboard from 'vue-clipboard2'

Vue.use(VueClipboard)
```

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default {
  // Some more config stuff
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/vueClipboard2.js', mode: 'client' },
  ]
}
```

Then you are able to use it globally, usually under `this.$something()`

Comment: I've just added into my project `https://github.com/webcore-it/nuxt-clipboard2` which is wrapper to `vueclipboard` for nuxt. and it is much more convinient and need less code. so I accept you answer, thanks